# Using React, what is the proper way to render an element with multiple nested elements?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Using React, how do I render a `<div>` with multiple nested `<div>`'s inside them? See code below.

```
var SubTrait = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    var subTraits = this.props.data;
    return (
    <div className = "subTraitContainer">
      <div>
        { subTraits.forEach(function(subTrait) {
          return (
            <div>
              <h4>{ subTrait.name }</h4>,
              Sub-Sub-Traits
              <SubSubTrait data={ subTrait.children } />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
});
```

The end result I get with this code is:

[image]

-edit-
Would the proper way to do this be to create my nodes first using `.forEach`, then passing the created nodes to the `render` function's `return`? (I'm looking at the React Tutorial at [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html). Would my original solution be possible, or is the only way to pre-create the nodes before returning them?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `map` instead of `forEach`. `forEach` returns nothing, so the result is:

```
<div class="subTraitContainer">
  <div></div>
<div>
```

`map` returns an array. It maps each element in the given array to something new. For example, you could map an array of `User`s to their `username`s. If you use `map` instead of `forEach`, you will get an array of `<div>`s, which should do what you expected.